# Convering bandwidth (frequency) to bit rate without knowledge of the modulation?

Tags: modulation, bandwidth

How would i convert a bandwidth of say 30kHz to bps if I only know the number of bits per sample (4)? (and I was using a two chanel system). I am assuming it is simply 30KHz * 2 * 4 but this may be wrong

Comment: Where is the 4 number coming from? Is that the number of bits per sample?

Comment: What is the signal-noise-ratio, if this is a data link?

Comment: If you're trying to answer a homework (or exam, or ...) question, please share the exact wording of the question.

Comment: To first order you can estimate the channel capacity using the Shannon-Hartley theorem.  That will show that you need to assume a desired SNR. This is often related to the modulation you are using and the channel characteristics between the Tx and Rx, and the practical capability of the receiver.

Comment: (See also: en.wikipedia on [channel capacity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity).)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what the sampling rate is. According to the [Nyquist Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate), you'll need to sample at twice the analog bandwidth to achieve alias-free sampling.

So assuming you want 60 kHz sampling, your total data rate will be:

60 kSamples/sec * 2 channels * 4 bits per sample = 480 kbps.

Comment: I think you're reading the question as if the OP is sampling the signal and want to work out the bit-rate of the result. But my interpretation of the question is that the OP wants to know what the potential data bit-rate would be using that 30kHz as a communication channel.

Comment: Yep, on a second read you are probably correct.